# Jquery .on("change", function() doesn't fire after content is generated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a Jquery script which should be fired when a file input changes. It works in a static page, but when content is generated it doesn't respond. Where is my problem?

```
$("#file_input").on("change", function(){
Code To Execute
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("change", "#file_input", function() {
```

Reason being -- these events are bound at run time. If your content isn't there at time, there's nothing to bind to! `document` in the above example is whatever the container is that has your appended content and also existed at run time.

Comment: Phew... So simple. I knew I was missing something. Thanks!